# Extract field after colon for lines where field before colon matches pattern

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a file `file1` which looks as below:

```
tool1v1:1.4.4
tool1v2:1.5.3
tool2v1:1.5.2.c8.5.2.r1981122221118
tool2v2:32.5.0.abc.r20123433554
```

I want to extract value of `tool2v1` and `tool2v2`
My output should be `1.5.2.c8.5.2.r1981122221118` and `32.5.0.abc.r20123433554`.

I have written the following `awk` but it is not giving correct result:

```
awk -F: '/^tool2v1/ {print $2}' file1
awk -F: '/^tool2v2/ {print $2}' file1
```

Comment: `awk -F':' '$1~/tool2v[12]/ {print $2}' file1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

grep -E can also do the job:

```
grep -E "tool2v[12]" file1 |sed 's/^.*://'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter with grep:

```
grep '\(tool2v1\|tool2v2\)'
```

And then remove the part before the : with sed:

```
sed 's/^.*://'
```

This sed operation means:

```
^ - match from beginning of string
.* - all characters
up to and including the :
```

... and replace this matched content with nothing.

The format is `sed 's/<MATCH>/<REPLACE>/'`

Whole command:

```
grep '\(tool2v1\|tool2v2\)' file1|sed 's/^.*://'
```

Result:

```
1.5.2.c8.5.2.r1981122221118
32.5.0.abc.r20123433554
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a grep that supports Perl compatible regular expressions such as GNU grep, you can use a variable-sized look-behind:

```
$ grep -Po '^tool2v[12]:\K.*' infile
1.5.2.c8.5.2.r1981122221118
32.5.0.abc.r20123433554
```

The `-o` option is to retain just the match instead of the whole matching line; `\K` is the same as "the line must match the things to the left, but don't include them in the match".

You could also use a normal look-behind:

```
$ grep -Po '(?<=^tool2v[12]:).*' infile
1.5.2.c8.5.2.r1981122221118
32.5.0.abc.r20123433554
```

And finally, to fix your awk which was almost correct (and as pointed out in a comment):

```
$ awk -F: '/^tool2v[12]/ { print $2 }' infile
1.5.2.c8.5.2.r1981122221118
32.5.0.abc.r20123433554
```

Answer (score 0):

the question has already been answered though, but you can also use pure bash to achieve the desired result

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
while read line;do
  if [[ "$line" =~ ^tool2v* ]];then
      echo "${line#*:}"
  fi
done < ./file1.txt
```

the `while` loop reads every line of the `file.txt`, `=~` does a regexp match to check if the value of `$line` variable if it starts with `toolv2`, then it trims `:` backward